# trying to find maximum torsional stress

Tags: mechanical-engineering, torque, stresses

I was wondering how I could get Ttmax (maximum torsional stress) or rather what the formula for it could be

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tc/J where:

- T: internal torque in the shaft
- c: radius of the circular rod
- J: Polar moment of inertia (pi*d^4/32 for a solid circular shaft)